# How to make subtree items respond to click event in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, desktop-application

I have a tree control in an MFC application. I have a function which displays a message box when the tree control is clicked. But I want the individual tree items and sub items to be clickable. I am new to MFC so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to the question. There's not much we can do if we can't see your code.

Comment: Items and child items are clickable by default. You don't have to do anything. Since apparently those items aren't clickable for you, you have to show a [mcve], so that we understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You get a notification with [`NM_DBLCLK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/nm-dblclk-tree-view)
2. The first click of the double click will select the item. You can retrieve the item that is currently selected and double clicked with [`TVM_GETNEXTITEM` `TVGN_CARET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvm-getnextitem). The MFC function is `CTreeCtrl::GetSelectedItem`